# how to connect folders in different file on same machine

Tags: php, html, xampp

Hi I am using xampp and for some reason my files are not connecting
one file is

```
http://localhost/series/hitcoun/
```

the other is

```
http://localhost/series/database/connect.inc.php
```

I tried using

```
require "../database/connect.inc.php";
```

in

```
http://localhost/series/hitcoun/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not seeing a fatal error try adding this to the top of your script

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

This will display any error that occur.

Try

```
require _DIR_ . "../database/connect.inc.php";
```

Comment: can you explain what those two things do

Comment: The first to lines tell error_reporting is used to set the error reporting level at runtime. display_errors determines if the errors are displayed on the screen. These should only be turned on for development. _DIR_ is the path to the current file

Comment: Hi Aaron, could you share what the problem was as it may help others.

Comment: it was a problem in the <?php tag i put a space in the wrong area

Answer (score 2):

```
require '../file.php'; // server internal error 500
```

and http server (Apache 2.4.3) returned internal error 500.

Try

```
require '/../file.php';
```